# How to replace 1,2,3,4....7 with Monday, Tue, Wed,Thur.... in quick way in R?

Tags: r

I have data set with a column day of the week, the value in column is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. I would like to replace with "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...". Is there any way to do this in a quick way? Thank you!

I usually replace data in this way :

```
data$column[data$columnx==a,]<-y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a character vector of all days

```
x <- c(3, 2, 4, 5, 1)
days <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
```

and then just subset

```
days[x]
#[1] "Wednesday" "Tuesday"   "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"
```

Comment: One more question, if the column contains NA, then this method would not work, right?

Comment: @Steve if the column contains `NA` this will return `NA` as well. Try it with `x <- c(3, 2, 4, 5,NA, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

A quick way would be to use inbuilt constant `day.name` from `DescTools` using the column values as index

```
library(DescTools)
data$column <- day.name[data$column]
data$column
#[1] "Friday"    "Wednesday" "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Sunday"    "Tuesday"  NA
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(column = c(5, 3, 1, 4, 7, 2, NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to convert the column to a `factor` and set the `levels`
Example:

```
df <- data.frame(n = c(sample(1:7), NA))
df
   n
1  5
2  3
3  2
4  4
5  1
6  7
7  6
8 NA

df$n <- as.factor(df$n)
levels(df$n) <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")

df
          n
1    Friday
2 Wednesday
3   Tuesday
4  Thursday
5    Monday
6    Sunday
7  Saturday
8      <NA>
```